# Number theory: how many unit fractions can represent 3/2021

Tags: number-theory

My professor took this Question from an old Math book and asked it to my class.
I tried to solve it with Egyptian unit fraction or the greedy algorithm. I cant solve it.

The fraction 3/10 can be represented in exactly 2 ways as the sum of two unit fractions: 3/10 = 1/5 + 1/10 = 1/4 + 1/20

1. In how many ways can 3/2021 be represented as the sum of two unit fractions ?
2. Is there a positive integer n not divisible by 3 with the property that 3 / n can be represented in exactly 2021 ways as the sum of two unit fractions?

Comment: This question is from an  active competition: mathe-wettbewerbe.de/download/aufgaben-21-1.pdf .